# All django lists are appears twice in my templates for all templates

Tags: python, ajax, django, linked-list

In my django template whenever I execute a for loop in any of my project app templates it displays the whole page twice[image]

This is my **base.html**

```
**{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="icon" type="png" sizes="192x192" href="{% static 'media/icon-0.png' %}">
         <title>Virgin city - {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'static/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'static/css/theme.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'static/css/main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'static/css/base.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>

    {% include 'navbar.html' %}

        <div id="content">
        {% if messages %}
            <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
            <li class="{{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message|safe }}
            <a href="." class="close">✖</a>
            </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src=" http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js "></script>
        <script>
            var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
            function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
            }
            $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
            }
            });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            {% block domready %}
            {% endblock %}
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>**
```

And this is the **html** for the screenshot I have above. I copied the ajax which I used for the load the list while I scrolled through the page to display the list items.

Thanks in advance

This the ajax block *{% block domready %}*

```
{% block domready %}
    var page = 1;
var empty_page = false;
var block_request = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
var margin = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200;
if ($(window).scrollTop() > margin && empty_page == false &&
block_request == false) {
block_request = true;
page += 1;
$.get('?page=' + page, function(data) {
if(data == '') {
empty_page = true;
}
else {
block_request = false;
$('#image-list').append(data);
}
});
}
});
{% endblock %}}
```

Comment: The Django part looks correct. I bet your JavaScript loads content twice. I would suggest to: 1) check you html source code and see where your gallery got pasted into - it should paste it into the same place; 2) debug JS and see how many times it gets pasted.

Comment: I have looked through it but I cant see where the error is

Comment: I just added the ajax portion of the list html